# Is working in a company which deals with bank loans permissible?

Tags: riba, work

The main part of my work (non-Muslim company in non-Muslim country) is preparing export documents to buyers and corresponding with them. At the same time, I have to correspond with the local banks regarding their loans and interest. Not solely, but under the request of the boss. I am not a decision maker.  They are the one who instruct me to write letters to banks requesting loans.  As they need a lot of money for these kind of exports, they involve in lot of bank deals.

At the same time, they allow me to pray five times, and to pray Jummah  on Fridays. My work is 7 hours a day. Only 5 days per week.  After suffering two years without a proper job I got this one.  What is the opinion regarding this situation.

Do I have to quit from this job?